# A textbook's reading of the Born Interpretation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, born-rule

A textbook states the following:

> $P(x, t) \ dx $ is the probability that a measurement of the position of the particle
>   described by $\Psi (x, t)$, at time $ t$, will find it in the region $(x, x + dx)$.

I've never heard this before, and it hasn't shown up in Wikipedia or anything. I'm confused about that last bit.

The probability that it will find it in the region $(x,x+dx)$?

I don't understand this. Is it implying the parametrization (although there is no need to think about it in terms of this, but it might help me):

$$x = x$$
$$y = x + dx$$

If my interpretation makes sense, why is this the case? Why wouldn't it be in the region $(x,y)$? What's with the restriction on $y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just sloppy (but often used) physics language. $P(x,t)$ is the *spatial probability density* as a function of time. This means that if you want to know the probability of finding the particle in the spatial interval (along the $x$-axis) $(a,b)$ at time $t=t_0$ you would do: $$P=\int_a^b P(x,t_0)dx.$$ There is only 1 spatial dimension being considered here. There's no $y$, if by $y$ you mean a direction orthogonal to $x$.

Comment: Right, well I understand your definition of $P$, but I still don't get what *they're saying.*

Comment: They are saying exactly what I'm saying but instead of $a$ and $b$ they are using $x$ and $x+dx$ - and then the notion that $dx$ "is an infinitessimal" to get rid of the integral. It's sloppy language, but intuitively it makes sense.

Comment: Oh! Okay, okay. Gotcha.

Comment: It is a very old fashioned way of saying it; popular in the early 1900s.  Maybe it was a very old text book?